# Sending NS user authentication data with Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3 from mobile app to server issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, xcode8

I'm new to authentication development and am stumped.

When I touch (click on simulator) `Sign Up` button in the app to submit my user name and password Xcode log shows the following error,

```
20  Selfie                              0x0000000100479707 main + 55
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010393d65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Further more, this appears when I scroll up, and seems the first signs of an issue

```
2017-07-13 18:27:42.367 Selfie[75333:3951236] *** Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
[Selfie.ViewController signupBtnTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent 
to instance 0x7fc042c11250'
```

The desired result is for the app to send the built request to my remote server held by AWS. Here's the pre-dated tutorial I'm using:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift

Here is the repo for the app, in the specific view controller it seems the problem is in, and where I'm left off in the tutorials instruction (at the sign up btn):

https://github.com/tristanbnewman/rwenderlich-auth-selfie/blob/master/Selfie/ViewController.swift

I apologize ahead of time for any etiquettes I've missed in this post, if there's anything you all need to help me solving (likely something I've missed providing you) just let me know.

Comment: your @IBaction for signUp button is not properly connected to viewController.  See [here](http://i68.tinypic.com/2s77sck.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would suggest you to make breakpoints on each line of the  signupBtnTapped function and see what's happening.

The "unrecognized selector sent to instance" is probably related to how you connect your @IBAction with a button event. Have you connected touchUpInside event with your function in the storyboard?

The first exception is a generic exception which doesn't give much information. Making breakpoints should help you with this.